# How to update a single property using PATCH method in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to create a PATCH method to update a single property for my API but there is something I don't understand.

Comment: And what is it?

Comment: LOL. Did you forget the second part?

Comment: It's show null in console log

Comment: Please be more specific about the question. Add a working code fragment and a clear explanation of what you want to do

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should Clearly post your question, this is what i understand, i hope this will help you if you are using `request` npm in `node.js`

```
var request = require('request');

request.patch(
    //First parameter API to make post request
    'https://example.com/api/users',

    //The second parameter, DATA which has to be sent to API
    { json: {
        name: "paul rudd",
        movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"]
      } 
    },
    
    //The third parameter is a Callback function 
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
            console.log(response.statusCode);
        }
    }
);
```

[for more information read here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-requestpatch-method-in-node)

Comment: The `request()` module has been [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request#deprecated) and is not recommended for new code or new projects.  Use one of these [alternatives](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) instead.